# How to call a user defined function in another user defined function in C language ? There is an error in this program... please tell me what is that?

Tags: c, function, pointers

**Q. Write a function to compute the distance between two points and use it to develop another function that will compute the area of the triangle whose vertices are A(x1, y1), B(x2, y2), and C(x3, y3). Use these functions to develop a function which returns a value 1 if the point (x, y) lines inside the triangle ABC, otherwise returns a value 0.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float distance(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float dis;
    dis = sqrt((pow((x1-x2),2))+(pow((y1-y2),2)));
    return dis;
}
float area(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3)
{
    float aa;
    aa = ((x1*(y2-y3) + x2*(y3-y1) + x3*(y1-y2))/2);
    return aa;
}
int point(float a, float b, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3, float A)
{
    float area(float, float, float, float, float, float);
    float a1, a2, a3 ;
    a1=area(float a, float b,  float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3);
    a2=area(float x1, float y1, float a, float b, float x3, float y3);
    a3=area(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float a, float b);
    if(a1 + a2 + a3 == A)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main()
{
    float x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, a, b, di, A;
    int p;
    printf("Enter the first coordinate: ");
    scanf("%f %f",&x1,&y1);
    printf("Enter the second coordinate: ");
    scanf("%f %f",&x2,&y2);
    di = distance(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    printf("The distance is: %f\n",di);
    printf("Enter the third coordinate: ");
    scanf("%f %f",&x3,&y3);
    A = area(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
    printf("The area is: %f\n",A);
    printf("Enter the coordinate of point: ");
    scanf("%f %f",&a,&b);
    p = point(a,b,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,A);
    printf("\n%d",p);
    return 0;
}[Error that I am getting][1]
```

Comment: what do you think is `float area(float, float, float, float, float, float);` doing?

Comment: Please describe your error. I suspected it is the usage of variable `A` from a point where it is not visible...

Comment: what error are you getting? When asking questions, try to be as specific and detailed as you can by including the errors instead of simply saying you got an error. Also, you can definitely call a function within another function.

Comment: @StefanRiedel I have written this for the function prototype...

Comment: @AtulGautam the function is known there, it is just some lines above. Your problem is, btw., `a1=area(float a, float b,  float x2, float y2, float x3, float y3);` where it should be `a1=area(a, b,  x2, y2, x3, y3);`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the compiler error messages you get. If you are able to run the program, copy&paste the input you use, the actual output/result/behavior you get and the expected output/behavior. The data type of the arguments must be specified in the function definition but not in the function call. Probably you mean e.g. `a1=area(a, b,  x2, y2, x3, y3);` Comparing `float` (or `double`) values with `==` or `!=` may lead to wrong results because of the limited precision of the values. The function prototype must be written before the function that uses it, not inside.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help.. It compiled and run successfully..

Comment: The answer to your question is found in the chapter "functions" in your beginner-level C programming book. Contrary to popular belief, SO is not an interactive beginner tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to mostly be in your `point` function. The first line doesn't do anything to help you, so you could comment that out.

The main problem here is your calls to your area function. You put the data type in front of each of your arguments in the call. In my tests, this prevented compilation.

Change the lines where you call `point` and assign the values to `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` to the following:

```
a1=area(a, b, x2, y2, x3, y3);
a2=area(x1, y1, a,  b, x3, y3);
a3=area(x1, y1, x2, y2, a, b);
```

Do that and it should compile and run.